# Android - how to define a configurable size shape

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Following suggestions in few other posts, I implemented a circular button to be used in the app:

[image: circular button]

It is implemented using XML selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--  Non focused states
     -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/big_ring_button_unfocused" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/big_ring_button_unfocused" />
    <!--  Focused states
     -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/big_ring_button_focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/big_ring_button_focused" />
    <!--  Pressed
     -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/big_ring_button_pressed" />
</selector>
```

The contents of the ..._unfocused file (the others just change colors):

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring"
android:innerRadius="@dimen/big_ring_button_inner_radius"
android:thickness="@dimen/big_ring_button_thickness"
android:useLevel="false">

<solid android:color="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

I'd like to use this template for all rounded buttons in my app, but since the text inside the buttons change, the size of the button itself should change.

I thought that I might be able to accomplish this programmatically, so I checked the documentation of [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) - there is no method there to change `innerRadius` attribute.

Currently I have 4 XML files per each round button (selector, unfocused, focused and pressed) which is extremely ugly and will become a pain in the neck to maintain.

How could I make this button configurable in size (either XML or programmatically)?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you could set the text in a TextView with the proper size scaling, then retrieve the dimensions, double the size for the radius and use that?

Comment: @user3427079, "double the size for the radius" - how do I do this without creating additional xml's for this specific button?

Comment: textView.getWidth() * 2, something like that I imagine

Comment: If you ensure that all of your buttons are layout as squares, then you can simple use an oval shape, and define it's padding to be some value greater than it's stroke width.

Comment: I dont think its a good approach to expand your circle with respect to text inside it programatically. Consider a long text like "Sync your Folder" as it would expand circle significantly and if you have another button next to it named "Sync" which will have small in radius. It would look awkward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the `innerRadius` attribute programmatically, as it's only read from XML attributes when inflating (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9392618/82788)).

However, you could achieve more or less the same effect programmatically, by using a custom drawable to draw the ring. For example:

```
public class RoundBorderDrawable extends GradientDrawable
{
    private static final int RING_THICKNESS = 20;
    private static final int PADDING = 8;
    private static final int NORMAL_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    private static final int PRESSED_COLOR = Color.RED;

    private Paint mPaint;

    public RoundBorderDrawable()
    {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(RING_THICKNESS);
        mPaint.setColor(NORMAL_COLOR);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet)
    {
        boolean result = super.onStateChange(stateSet);

        int color = NORMAL_COLOR;
        for (int i = 0; i < stateSet.length; i++)
        {
            if (stateSet[i] == android.R.attr.state_pressed)
                color = PRESSED_COLOR;
        }

        if (color != mPaint.getColor())
        {
            mPaint.setColor(color);
            invalidateSelf();
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.draw(canvas);
        int diameter = Math.min(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()) - RING_THICKNESS - 2 * PADDING;
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, diameter / 2, mPaint);
    }
}
```

This will draw a circle that fits inside the `Button` dimensions (I assumed you wanted to draw a circle even for non-square buttons).

Then just set a new instance of `RoundBorderDrawable` as the background of your button (the properties that are constants in this example could, of course, be supplied via the constructor or with setter methods).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can't test your workaround right now, but it seems the most promising approach right now.

Comment: @Vasiliy We've been using something of this kind in our projects; hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better approach for doing this. Instead of `Ring` use `Oval` and  give stroke with color white and width `@dimen/big_ring_button_thickness`
but this doesn't give you circular shape. To achieve circular shape your button should be square, I mean width and height of the button should be same.