# Circular Text Views like Google Messenger

Tags: android

I would like to display letters inside of circles exactly the way Google Messenger does it, like this:

[image: Google Messenger circular text views]

I tried using this drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/primary_color" android:width="2dip"/>
<solid android:color="@color/primary_color"/>
```

as the background for a text view, but that went disastrously wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide some description of how it went disastrously wrong. Also, this post may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931909/android-how-to-define-a-configurable-size-shape

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You was almost close to answer.

Create a drawable resources file under drawable folder: *circular_textview.xml*

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#4286F5"/>
```

Set this drawable as your textView's background.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="C"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"/>
```

That's it

[image]

Comment: Nice! Very perfect answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I came up with.

[image]

I used `TextView`s with a `layer-list` background. The background fits the size of the view it's loaded in, so in order to have a circle you can force the `TextView` to have the same width and height.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:text="A"/>
```

I have hardcoded text, size, width and height, but you could manage them at runtime. `fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"` lets you use, if available, the thin typeface which might be better. The layer-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#321a1a1a"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@color/red_700"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

First item is to get the fake shadow shown, but you can get rid of that. Also, you can remove its offset `android:top="1dp"`. This way you will have a circular 1dp ring outside (while now shadow is cast only at the bottom and in both sides).

Again, I have hardcoded colors but you can change to what you want.

Comment: Nice! Very perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it that way.
Path res/drawable/oval.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
    android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
    android:angle="45"/>
<padding android:left="7dp"
    android:top="7dp"
    android:right="7dp"
    android:bottom="7dp" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

This code gets your textview and applies the shape as background to it:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable shape = res. getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_box);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.textview);
tv.setBackground(shape);
```

It's from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 0):

Late but not least.
I'd suggest what I used in one of my projects by Amulya Khare.

https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable