# Change ring thickness programmatically

Tags: android, xml

HI I am developing an application for Android. In my activity it contains one Linear layout. I want to set the ring type background. So I use the following code.

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.7"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="16dp"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
   </shape>
```

It is working fine. Now I want to change the thickness in above code programmatically. How can I change this? I did R&D for that but didn't get answer.

Comment: what you have did so far?

Comment: @Amy i made a circle using shape in drawable package i.e background.xml  and i set my layout background   android:background="@drawable/background" it's working fine but i want to change the thickness of ring programmaticatlly to make compatable with all the screen size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the thickness programmatically may be involved. The answers to the question [Creating ring shape in Android code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346112/creating-ring-shape-in-android-code) provide some insight.

If you simply want to scale up or scale down the thickness of the ring proportionally as the display size increases/decreases as you mention in the comments, then you may want to consider using the `android:thicknessRatio` or the `android:innerRadiusRatio` attribute in your XML to do so and delete the `android:thickness` attribute. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for details.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got the another way.

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.7"
android:shape="ring"
android:thickness="@dimensions/thickness_of_circle"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
```

And i  create Different values folder for different screens . Like

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

[image]

Define the thickness according to screen size in the dimension file of all the values folder it will automatically take the file according to screen size.