# How to set inner radius on circle shape in drawable programatically in Android?

Tags: android, drawable

I have an xml drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="@dimen/button_numpad_size"
android:thicknessRatio="1"
android:shape="ring"
android:useLevel="false" >
```

How do I change innerRadius through code and then refresh it?

Comment: check this http://androidfreakstuff.blogspot.in/2015/09/ripple-effect-in-android-for.html , in the library doing same thing

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9442028/4049612](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9442028/4049612)

Comment: Refer  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Comment: Is there any solution to this? I'm looking forward to solving this issue.